# Display the name of a current log-on user of web-app which uses Spring, Spring Security, Hibernate, jQuery, Backbone, AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, backbone.js

How can I display the name of a current user in the HTML page? I'm new to Javascript/jQuery, unfortunately.
So I have a Java app created with the help of Spring MVC, Spring Security, Hibernate, jQuery, Backbone.js.
I do not use JSP and EL.
My app is one-page AJAX-style. My user (=client) logins successfully, controller redirects him to client's personal page and one method of a controller returns me the name of the user as a String. How should I use it to be shown in the page?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/client", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String client(Locale locale, Model model, ModelMap modelMap, Principal principal) {
    String currentUser = getActiveUser(modelMap, principal);
    System.out.println("Current user is " + currentUser);
              /*The username of the current user is written in the
                    Eclipse console successfully*/
    return "forward:/pages/client.html";
}

public String getActiveUser(ModelMap modelMap, Principal principal) {
        String name = principal.getName();
        modelMap.addAttribute("userName", name);
        return name;
    }
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Something like this:**

//import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String printUser(ModelMap model) {

      User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
      String name = user.getUsername(); //get logged in username

      model.addAttribute("username", name);
      return "homepage";

  }
```

**(or)**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String printUser(ModelMap model) {

          Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
          String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username

          model.addAttribute("username", name);
          return "homepage";
}
```

Comment: My method getActiveUser() returns me the name. My question is: "How can I display the name of a current user in the HTML page?". It is JAVASCRIPT-related question. So my model got a username. What to do next to display it in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html

Comment: As I said before, I do not use JSP and EL.

Answer (score 0):

`HTML` is static, and you can not put the logged in user name dynamically into it. Change it to jsp and above answers will help you to display the logged in user name.

Comment: Won't Javascript/JQuery help me? Using templates, for example?

Comment: Nope javascript or jquery all are at client side, you can't pass server data to it dynamically.